# Contemporary PHP patterns to deal with concurrency, or is this not an issue?

Tags: php, concurrency

the last time I've dabbled with php was way back in 2004, those days of nukephp when it was acceptable to create counters where the script reads a file, increments it and writes it back.  Back then when I wrote those types of scripts I wasn't worried about locking the file and having the next request die() if it cannot get the lock.

Now I am. And I am sure many of you are. So how do contemporary modern web developers deal with this issue? Are there new systematic approaches towards it? Ajax itself does not suggest a way to deal with this, as far as I know. It seems to just be about asynchronous requests, nothing about how the server should handle two clients asking update a file at the same time with two separate values.

Is there anyway, mechanism, model, pattern, architecture, in the world of PHP that can bring me back to, if only the illusion of, atomicity I once felt I had with those earlier days? Is there any resources that I should engage if I want to become more contemporary creating web services like stackexchange/utube comments?

edit: how do I create a simple counter script utilizing a framework in php that provides lockless currency, and doesn't rely on a database to handle reconciling the transactions, and something that can work with data on the file system (this data is unstructured, doesn't need to be in the database).

Comment: Can you provide a short coding sample of what you think is a problem? I'm struggling to understand the concurrency issue you are having

Comment: Done, I gave an example of a problem.

Comment: SQL based solution is the simpliest. Just use AUTO_INCREMENT field and LAST_INSERT_ID() and you'll get new ID every time. Using files is not that bad as most filesystem accesses are cached anyway by OS. PHP has a few accelerates which can be used to store custom variables, like xcache or eaccelerator. And semaphores is always an option.  EDIT: Also memcache is widely used, especially in multi-server approach.

Answer (score 1):

Uhh... hate to break it to you, but seeking "lockless concurrent flat-file updates" is like trying to find a flying pig ice-skating in hell.

The solution, *lock files*, hasn't changed in the last 8 years and likely will not change... ever. It is fundamental. Either use locks, or a database. It doesn't matter that the data has no structure, you're probably *already* using a database, so either create a field in a table somewhere or create a more robust structure to allow you to delve into your data a little more deeply than a simply tally of all hits since an arbitrary date.

```
TABLE Articles
  ID INT PK
  ...

TABLE Viewcount
  Date        DATE  PK
  Article_ID  INT   PK
  NumViews    INT

INSERT INTO Viewcount (Date, Article_ID, NumViews)
  VALUES(TODAY(), 12345, 1)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE NumViews=NumViews+1
```

As a note, if you were using a compiled language like C you could write a daemon to sit on that file and increment it, but you'd basically just be moving the lock file to a bool sitting somewhere in RAM.